# Empirical Bayes for normal likelihood and normal prior

Tags: mixed-model, empirical-bayes

Here's my simulated data:

```
from scipy import stats

# Simulated dataset
n_sim = 1000
mu = 0
sigma = 20

df_sim = (
    pd.DataFrame({
        'delta_true': stats.norm.rvs(mu, sigma, n_sim),
        'se_observed': np.abs(stats.norm.rvs(20, 10, n_sim))
    })
    .assign(delta_observed=lambda d: stats.norm.rvs(d['delta_true'], d['se_observed']))
    .drop(columns='delta_true')
)
```

I want to estimate $\mu$ and $\sigma$ (I guess using MLE?) without setting a full Bayesian model so I can then shrink the `delta_observed` estimates. If needed, we can set $\mu =0$. Solution can be either in R or Python. Further resources appreciated. Thank you!